# Why does Val(5d886) or Val(5e886) cause an OverflowException?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

Example code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MessageBox.Show(Val(TextBox1.Text), "Val of text input")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Anyhow out of simple curiosity I am wondering why it does this?

From some other posts & personal experience I know VAL(expression) isn't recommended & is just a legacy function from VB6 days.  I tried every other alphabet letter & none caused this issue, I also tried a couple variations & it appears any number after d or e add that many zeros (seems like its multiplying). I understand that the value may be overflowing the data-type VAL placed it in. I see e is the default variable for the sub-procedure, so that's probably why, but I can't figure out any logic to d.

Please make it noted I am very new to VB.NET, just got down with a college course & haven't built any actual apps. Furthermore our teacher seemingly didn't teach us error-handling which I am very interested in, as my current work situation has some rather old apps that have issues. Would also like any recommended error-handling articles/readings

Comment: Post valid code, Val(5d886) cannot compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Val() function "returns the numbers contained in a string as a numeric value of appropriate type" (cit. from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9(v=vs.71).aspx).
If you set a string value like 5exxx it means 5 * 10^xxx; but pay attention: the function returns a double and double goes approximately from ±5.0 x 10^-324 to ±1.7 x 10^308; so, for example, the string 5e307 works but 5e308 doesn't, returning overflow.
If you use some other letters "function stops reading the string at the first character it cannot recognize as part of a number", so it doesn't return overflow.

I hope it was helpful. Have a nice new year!

Comment: I kind of understood that was happening (the multiplication). That article you linked I had read, it says "stops reading the string at the first character it cannot recognize as part of a number". However I still do not understand why d & e do this & no other characters do? Furthermore how do you know it returns it as a double vs say single, integer, etc?

Comment: The strings xxxEyyy and xxxDyyy are two ways to write a number in scientific notation. Val function returns a double result for it recognizing a correct number format. Agreeding with help file, the function always returns a double except for the case that there is a char in input; in that case the fucntion returns an integer.

Comment: You nailed my question. A quick google search shows a website addressing this: http://www.powerbasic.com/support/help/pbcc/val_function.htm. Would love to see a Microsoft article at least explaining the e & d. Doubt it would address it in context of Val (how it would interpret). Feel free to also address my last sentence in the original question if you could

Comment: Maybe you can find useful the MSDN page on VB.NET errors: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973849.aspx; or this quick tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13658/VB-NET-Error-Handling; however there are a lot of tutorials online about it. If you think my post is useful you may check it as an answer. Thank you!

Comment: Here is a s function that will extract just the numbers (consider it home-made Val2): http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?p=1315649#post1315649